# Referencing a variable inside a function inside a $scope member function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

This is more of a general javascript closures and scope function, but I'll ask it in the context of angular where I encountered it. Lets say I have the following controller:

```
var Controller = function ($scope, factory) {
        $scope.Letter = 'A';

        /*
            Some other code
            .
            .
            . 
        */

        $scope.OnClick = function() {
            console.log($scope.Letter);
            SomethingWithCallBack('a param', 34, function() {
                console.log($scope.Letter);
            });
        }
};
```

Assume something happens where $scope.Letter is updated, then OnClick is fired. The $scope.Letter inside of OnClick keeps the original value. I can fix this by changing the line to `console.log(this.Letter);`. However, I cannot do that inside the anonymous function in SomethingWithCallBack(). There I currently solve the problem by assigning a variable the value of `this.Letter` as follows.

```
var myLetter = this.letter;
SomethingWithCallBack('a param', 34, function() {
    console.log(myLetter);
});
```

Is there some way to reference "outer this" inside the callback so I don't have to assign the variable?

Comment: what do you mean that $scope.letter in the onclick keeps the original value? because that is not true. If you update $scope.letter, then it will be the new value when you call onClick. now, you do seem to use primitives directly on the scope, so that will give you problems with inherited scopes which might cause you to think it doesn't change

Comment: What do you mean "Use primitives on the scopes?" You mean scope members that are primatives (ints strings and dates)?

Comment: correct. By setting a primitive value on the scope from a child scope, the parent scope value will not be changed. The child scope will have its own (same named) field with its own value. For that reason you should always put objects on the scope of which you set a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem when you are writing javascript

All you need to do is store this in another variable before attaching the event listener.

```
var that = this;
SomethingWithCallBack('a param', 34, function() {
    console.log(that.myLetter);
});
```

Comment: Storing this in another variable can make things simple. Hoping there is a better way.